# Is there any way to fix "Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'max_date'" without using a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm getting this error when I try do do a simple join in Hive .

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 a
INNER JOIN table_2 b
ON a.sales_amount between b.min_sales_amount and b.max_sales_amount
```

`Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'max_date`

I know you can use a WHERE clause but is there other way to get this working? I have a large script, and I don't want to have to change every join.

It's pretty absurd that it doesn't allow you to do this type of join.

Comment: Given that “max_date” doesn’t appear in the SQL you’ve provided, it seems unlikely that that SQL has generated that error message. Please also update your question with the ddl for the two tables

Comment: 1- This error is a message from Hive semantic analyzer, nothing to do with Hue which simply displays it. 2- Most likely means that you have max_date column in both tables, and OLD versions of Hive were unable to resolve such ambiguity. What Hive version are you using?

Comment: Not sure why a large script matters. Did you not test one of your joins before writing the rest? Otherwise, find-replace should be easy? Also, I feel like you should be union-ing the tables, then using where filter, rather than joining against an inequality, or rather joining on some sales id